# Does adverb placement change the meaning in the following phrase?

Tags: meaning

Is there a difference in meaning between "to positively resolve situations" and "to resolve situations positively." Sorry, I thought there was a difference in that the question asks if in the first phrase if the adverb modifies the infinitive and in the second modifies the infinitive phrase was there a different in meaning such as the first phrase indicating all situations were settled and in the second that the situations were favorably settled.

Comment: If you read through all the answers, I think you'll find why these are possibly different in the context of your entire sentence, which you have not provided here.

Comment: Stretching a point, you could in principle contrive contexts where *positively* functions more as an emphasiser *(definitely, unquestionably)* than a simple adverb *(in a positive rather than a negative fashion)*. "We're not just trying to *ameliorate* these problems - we're trying to positively *resolve* them."